# Android Studio - IntelliJ new java class wizard

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

After last Android Studio update, there's the following new java class wizard right after picking the name:

[image]

Couldn't find any guide on how to use it because it doesn't auto-completes anything.

Is there a way to return to the old wizard?

Comment: I actually thought it was some debug window some developer forgot to take out before release as it looks so odd, like everything written in caps. It also serves no actual purpose.

Answer (score 7):

You can disable this dialog by reset your class template to default in Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates:
[image: screenshot]

This dialog shown when template has variables which can not be provided automatically. I think studio installer forgot update templates from previous setup where new class dialog had more options.

Answer (score 1):

> Couldn't find any guide on how to use it because it doesn't auto-completes anything.

From the Android Studio [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/create-java-class#variables):

> Android Studio replaces file template variables with values in the generated Java file. You enter the values in the Create New Class dialog. The template has the following variables that you can use:
>
> - IMPORT_BLOCK - A newline-delimited list of Java import statements
>   necessary to support any superclass or interfaces, or an empty string
>   (""). For example, If you only implement the Runnable interface and
>   extend nothing, this variable will be `import java.lang.Runnable;\n`.
>   If you implement the Runnable interface and extend the Activity
>   class, it will be `import android.app.Activity;\nimportjava.lang.Runnable;\n`.
> - VISIBILITY -
>   Whether the class will have public access or not. It can have a value
>   of `PUBLIC` or `PACKAGE_PRIVATE`.
> - SUPERCLASS - A single class name, or
>   empty. If present, there will be an extends `${SUPERCLASS}` clause
>   after the new class name.
> - INTERFACES - A comma-separated list of
>   interfaces, or empty. If present, there will be an implements
>   `${INTERFACES}` clause after the superclass, or after the class name if
>   there’s no superclass. For interfaces and annotation types, the
>   interfaces have the extends keyword.
> - ABSTRACT - Whether the class
>   should be abstract or not. It can have a value of `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
> - FINAL - Whether the class should be final or not. It can have a value
>   of `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

> Is there a way to return to the old wizard?

NO. you cannot revert back to old style new class dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this for the class template:

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end

#if (${IMPORT_BLOCK} != "")${IMPORT_BLOCK}
#end
#parse("File Header.java")

#if (${VISIBILITY} != "pr" || ${VISIBILITY} == "")public #end 
#if (${ABSTRACT} == "y" || ${ABSTRACT} == "true")abstract #end 
#if (${FINAL} == "y" || ${FINAL} == "true")final #end 
class ${NAME} #if (${SUPERCLASS} != "")extends ${SUPERCLASS} #end 
#if (${INTERFACES} != "")implements ${INTERFACES} #end {
}
```

define the template in Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates